# InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter Fails While Writing Keywords to Photos from Recent Cameras

Tags: c#, metadata, jpeg, imaging, xmp

I have successfully used the InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter to write Keywords to many photos taken by many cameras, including when I need to extend the metdata padding. However for photos taken by recent cameras the TrySave method always returns false for Keywords. Does anyone know why this might be and how I might solve this?

```
        using (Stream jpgFileStream = File.Open(tempPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            // BitmapCacheOption.None tells the decoder to delay decoding until encoding. The JPEG 
            // encoder understands that the input was a JPEG and just copies over the image bits without decompressing 
            // and recompressing them to perform a lossless operation.
            BitmapDecoder jpgDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(jpgFileStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);

            if (jpgDecoder.Frames[0] != null && jpgDecoder.Frames[0].Metadata != null)
            {
                InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter metadataJpgWriter = jpgDecoder.Frames[0].CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter();

                metadataJpgWriter.SetQuery("System.Keywords", Keywords.ToArray());;

                if (metadataJpgWriter.TrySave())
                {
                    traySaveSuccessful = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It could be that the newer files compress the metadata padding better? `InPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter`, as the name implies, writes it's data in place so it doesn't require reencoding but this means that it will fail to write metadata if there is no room left to write the metadata. I'm not sure what else you can do apart from reencode the image at that point.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350271/2557997

Comment: 'including when I need to extend the metdata padding' - I missed that initially my bad, I have no clue.

Comment: Thanks @Blam .  My code is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35350271/2557997 . I've followed https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1017/entry-2305-updating-jpeg-metadata-wthout-loss-of-quality/ as it handles metadata padding increases when TrySave fails and is lossless. It works very well for photos taken with older cameras.